# best data storage for android app with lots of data

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which have fifty record saved locally and each record have image, text view and detail view so i am confused to select the correct storage for my app .

Comment: but why should i use i dont need relational system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As, i having same scenario just like you in my FoodRecipe App and having long list with images and detail, and storing in local Database using **SQLite database**

its very easy to manage database and i personally like it because we can Query on database and get data as we want..

**Advantage of SQLite :** [click here](https://www.quora.com/Why-should-we-use-SQLite-in-Android-development)

Comment: but sqlit is relational database it should be used when u have multiple tables to connect them

Comment: from where you r saving data i mean from JSON or else how?

Comment: if you are storing data from JSON then you can Write Json to your cache dir. and read it and whenever get online just update it. There is no need to use Database.

Answer (score 0):

SqliteDatabase is useful because you can easily manage image data in database.

Answer (score 0):

you can use realm database instead of SQLite database

https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/

Answer (score 0):

You should use `SQLite` database because :

- Android comes in with built in `SQLite` database implementation.
- `SQLite` supports all the relational database features. In order to access this  database, you don't need to establish any kind of connections for it like `JDBC,ODBC` e.t.c